# Linux find command with multiple ORs

Tags: linux, find

Trying to get a list of all of the video files in ~/files. Gentoo 2.7.

```
find ~/files -type f "( -iname *.mp4 -o -iname *.mov -o iname *.mkv )" | head
find: paths must precede expression: `( -iname *.mp4 -o -iname *.mov -o iname *.mkv )'
```

I've tried removing the quotes and escaping the parentheses and asterisks, and removing the type restriction, but same error.

Limiting the filetypes to two with a single OR works:

```
find ~/files -type f -iname \*.mp4 -o -iname \*.mov
```

I feel like I'm probably just fundamentally misunderstanding something about the find command, I'm just not sure what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the parentheses and the wildcards separately so they remain separate arguments. `find` doesn't like it when they're combined into a single argument.

Also the final `-iname` is missing a dash.

```
find ~/files -type f "(" -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.mov" -o -iname "*.mkv" ")" | head
```